# checking if element is in linked list

Tags: python, linked-list

I’m trying to implement a method that returns the index of a node at a particular index.
I can successfully retrieve the index when the element exists; however when it doesn’t I get an error 'NoneType' object has no attribute ‘data’ I can’t quite get why that happens.
here are my linked list and node classes

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,data = None,next = None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next
class Listy:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
```

and this is my get_index function

```
    def get_index(self,key):
        temp = self.head
        count = 0
        while temp.data != key:
            temp = temp.next
            count += 1
        print(count)
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: You eventually reach the last item, which doesn't have `next` set. How do you handle that?

Comment: Yes I knew this was the problem, but I couldn’t solve the issue.Could you give me any hint?I cannot find an answer.

Comment: *"that returns the index of a node at a particular index"*: that doesn't sound right: if you have a particular index, why would you return the index? I suppose you mean *"that returns the index of a node **with a specific value**"*.

Answer (score 1):

You get an error because you are trying to get property 'data' of 'temp' in the while loop but your 'temp' is 'None' because you assigned it to 'self.head' which is actually 'None' in case of empty list. I hope this makes sense

Comment: yes, but I don’t quite understand how I can solve the issue.I used the same method for all the other function but I didn’t get this type of error.

Answer (score 0):

The root caused is because the last node of LinkedList returns None,
let's change a bit Your Listy class code to avoid None value.

```
class Listy:
    def __init__(self, nodes=None):
        self.head = None
        if nodes is not None:
            node = Node(nodes.pop(0))
            self.head = node
            for elem in nodes:
                node.next = Node(elem)
                node = node.next
    
    def get_index(self, key):
        temp = self.head
        count = 0
        currentNode = temp.data
        while temp is not None:
            if count == key:
                currentNode = temp.data
                break
            temp = temp.next
            count += 1
        return currentNode
```

Let's try to call:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    nodes = ["a", "b", "c"]
    ll = Listy(nodes)
    idx_1 = ll.get_index(0)
    idx_2 = ll.get_index(1)

    print(idx_1)
    print(idx_2)
```

Return will be as follow:

```
a
b
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is too optimistic about *finding* the key: it does not check whether you have reached the end of the list before finding the value, and so `temp` will become `None` resulting in an exception when `temp.data` is evaluated.

So change your loop to make sure that `temp` is still not `None`, and *return* the index when the key is found (instead of *printing* it):

```
def get_index(self, key):
    temp = self.head
    count = 0
    while temp:
        if temp.data == key:
            return count
        temp = temp.next
        count += 1
```

Note how this will return `None` when the key is not found.